# Combining Remove and Replace Function in MS SQL Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder, ssrs-2019

A field gives me the following string:

#$TEXTA#$TEXTB#$TEXTC

I want to remove the #$-chars and seperate the values by a new line. In addition I want to replace special characters (&). In the end it should look like this:

TEXTA
TEXTB
TEXTC

So I use this code:

```
=Replace(Replace(Fields!My_Field.Value,"&amp;","&"),"#$",Environment.NewLine)
```

The string starts with #$, so this code makes a new line in the beginning, which I want to avoid by using this code:

```
=Right(First(Fields!My_Field.Value, "DATASET"), Len(First(Fields!My_Field.Value, "DATASET"))-2)
```

I want to remove the first two chars **before** the replace function starts. My problem is, that I dont know how to combine these two functions to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without testing this....

I think you should just be able to replace your reference to the field in your first expression, with your second expression, like this.

```
=Replace(
        Replace(
               Right(First(Fields!My_Field.Value, "DATASET"), Len(First(Fields!My_Field.Value, "DATASET"))-2)
               ,"&amp;"
               ,"&"
        ),
        "#$",
        Environment.NewLine
        )
```